# Objective-C – UILocalNotification alertBody length

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm looking for some documentation to find the maximum length of the `alertBody` of a `UILocalNotification` before it will get clipped in either the notification center (banner) or in a popup alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it wasn't that easy. It also depends on the character widths. I suppose you just have to make room to support different character widths.

Comment: Got a source for that, out of interest?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any specific limit documented.  However, you can try it out and see that the notification drop down shows about 80 characters.  This is on an iPhone 5S with iOS 7.1. 
[image: screen shot of notification drop down]
The notification center shows more of the message.  In this case about 138 characters before it starts truncating.

Of course with proportionally space fonts the number of characters depends on the width of those characters, the iPhone has less width to display text than the iPad, and future version of iOS may change this.
[image]